# VIM zsh, bash and colors in command line on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, vim, shell, zsh

I have problem with VIM command line when calling system commands.
e.g. `!ls`, all command output colors aren't parsed by VIM. My system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with VIM 7.3.429 from Ubuntu repositories.

[image]

Is there any workaround for this problem?

---

EDIT:

[My vimrc file](https://bitbucket.org/exu/vim/raw/78cda201ac04/vimrc)

`:!echo $TERM` in VIM returns : `dumb`

---

EDIT2:

I found a simple workaround but it's not perfect

```
if [ "$VIM" ] && [ "$TERM" = "dumb" ] 
then 
    # For gvim's monochromatic :shell 
    PS1='\n\u@\h \w\n\$ ' 
    unalias ls 
    unalias grep 
fi
```

(It's working on bash)

Comment: `$ echo $TERM` and show us your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

2 Steps:

1) set TERM to something other than "dumb" in .bashrc. xterm should be fine, as it looks like you're on Ubuntu.

2) In .vimrc, add set t_Co=256. That tells vim you're on a 256 color terminal.

That should fix your problems.